# Remove hbox when unselected

Tags: javafx, radio-button, root

I would like to create menu with 3 radio buttons(comm,med,all). Where for example Comm button should create hbox, but when the other option is selected, this hbox should disapear, but it wont.

Could anyone set me to the right direction?
Thank you a lot.

Heres what Ive got:

```
comm.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                            if(comm.isSelected())
                                root.add(commBox, 0,1);
                            else if(med.isSelected()||all.isSelected())
                                root.getChildren().remove(commBox);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: You want to hide it to be able to display it another time or to just remove it completely? If it's the second option, why would you want to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onAction` handler for the radio button is invoked when an action is performed on *that button*. The radio button will become deselected when one of the *other buttons* in the same toggle group is selected. So your handler does not get invoked when the button is deselected.

Register a listener with the `selectedProperty` instead:

```
comm.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
    if (isNowSelected) {
        root.add(commBox, 0,1);
    } else {
        root.getChildren().remove(commBox);
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could register a listener with the toggle group:

```
// assuming the following existing code, or its equivalent:
ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
comm.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
med.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
all.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);

// then this will work:
toggleGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((obs, oldToggle, newToggle) -> {
    if (newToggle == comm) {
        root.add(commBox, 0, 1);
    } else {
        root.getChildren().remove(commBox);
    }
    // maybe more logic here to handle med or all selected...
});
```